# Browser try to download .pl file instead of executing it - apache2, perl cgi scripts, ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, perl, ubuntu, cgi

My ubuntu version is 15.04.
I followed the steps for configuring the server:

1. `sudo apt-get install apache2`
2. `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2`
3. `sudo apt-get install perl-debug`
4. `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2-dev`
5. `sudo apt-get install libapache2-request-perl libdatetime-perl`
6. `mkdir /var/www/cgi-bin`
7. `nano perltest.pl`

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl -w
   print "Content-type: test/html\r\n\r\n";
   print "Hello there!<br/>\nJust Testing. <br/>\n";

   for ($i=0; $i<10;$i++)
   {
   print $i."<br/>";
   }
   ```
8. `chmod a+x perltest.pl`
9. Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
   # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
   # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
   # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
   # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
   # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
   # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
   #ServerName www.example.com

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/

   # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
   # error, crit, alert, emerg.
   # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
   # modules, e.g.
   #LogLevel info ssl:warn


   < Files ~ "\.(pl|cgi)$">
   SetHandler perl-script
   PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::PerlRun
   Options +ExecCGI
   PerlSendHeader On
   < /Files>


   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/

   < Directory /var/www/cgi-bin/>
   AllowOverride None
   Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
    </Directory>


   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
   # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
   # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
   # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
   # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
   #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
   </VirtualHost>

   # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```
10. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` file is [here](https://ideone.com/O7zK0r)(line 5-11)
11. `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file is [here](https://ideone.com/RNt80S)(line 12-37)
12. Add lines to nano `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file is [here](https://ideone.com/7nhNjF)(line- (54-78))
13. In browser, hit http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/perltest.pl

But, the browser downloads the files. 
I am unable to understand the problems. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 print "Content-type: test/html\r\n\r\n";
                        ^
                      Here is your problem
```

should be `print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";`

goto root and restart the apache server in your machine by the following command

`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`